teleop_twist_keyboard not working with ROS2 Humble and Gazebo Fortress
I've been following the Articulated Robotics tutorial series on a Raspberry Pi 4B with Ubuntu 22.04 after switching to ROS2 Humble. However, when it comes to using the teleop_twist_keyboard to move the robot in Gazebo, I just can't get mine to move! Running ros2 topic info /cmd_vel while both the launch files and the teleop_twist_keyboard are running tells me that there are no nodes subscribed to it. But a namespace isn't set and in the tutorial it works right away, so I don't know why this is the case. Here are my files so far:
launch_sim.launch.py:
import os

from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import IncludeLaunchDescription, ExecuteProcess
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource
from launch_ros.actions import Node

def generate_launch_description():
    package_name='robot' #<--- CHANGE ME

    rsp = IncludeLaunchDescription(
                PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([os.path.join(
                    get_package_share_directory(package_name),'launch','rsp.launch.py'
                )]), launch_arguments={'use_sim_time': 'true'}.items()
    )

    gazebo = ExecuteProcess(
        cmd=['ign', 'gazebo', 'empty.sdf'],
        output='screen'
    )

    spawn_entity = Node(package='ros_gz_sim', executable='create',
                        arguments=['-topic', 'robot_description',
                                   '-entity', 'robot'],
                        output='screen')

#    diff_drive_spawner = Node(
#        package="controller_manager",
#        executable="spawner",
#        arguments=["diff_cont"],
#    )
#
#    joint_broad_spawner = Node(
#        package="controller_manager",
#        executable="spawner",
#        arguments=["joint_broad"],
#    )

    return LaunchDescription([
        rsp,
        gazebo,
        spawn_entity,
#        diff_drive_spawner,
#        joint_broad_spawner
    ])

rsp.launch.py:
import os

from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory

from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument
from launch_ros.actions import Node

import xacro


def generate_launch_description():

    # Check if we're told to use sim time
    use_sim_time = LaunchConfiguration('use_sim_time')

    # Process the URDF file
    pkg_path = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('robot'))
    xacro_file = os.path.join(pkg_path,'description','robot.urdf.xacro')
    robot_description_config = xacro.process_file(xacro_file)
    
    # Create a robot_state_publisher node
    params = {'robot_description': robot_description_config.toxml(), 'use_sim_time': use_sim_time}
    node_robot_state_publisher = Node(
        package='robot_state_publisher',
        executable='robot_state_publisher',
        output='screen',
        parameters=[params]
    )


    # Launch!
    return LaunchDescription([
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            'use_sim_time',
            default_value='false',
            description='Use sim time if true'),

        node_robot_state_publisher
    ])

robot.urdf.xacro:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro"  name="robot">

    <xacro:include filename="robot_core.xacro" />
    <xacro:include filename="gazebo_control.xacro"/>
    <xacro:include filename="lidar.xacro"/>

</robot>

gazebo_control.xacro:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">

    <gazebo>
        <plugin filename="libignition-gazebo-diff-drive-system.so" name="ignition::gazebo::systems::DiffDrive">

            <num_wheel_pairs>2</num_wheel_pairs>
            <left_joint>FL_wheel_joint</left_joint>
            <left_joint>RL_wheel_joint</left_joint>
            <right_joint>FR_wheel_joint</right_joint>
            <right_joint>RR_wheel_joint</right_joint>
            
            <max_wheel_torque>200</max_wheel_torque>
            <max_wheel_acceleration>200</max_wheel_acceleration>
            
            <odometry_frame>odom</odometry_frame>
            <robot_base_frame>base_link</robot_base_frame>
            
            <publish_odom>true</publish_odom>
            <publish_odom_tf>true</publish_odom_tf>
            <publish_wheel_tf>true</publish_wheel_tf>

        </plugin>
    </gazebo>


</robot>

As I'm working with arm64, I couldn't get Gazebo Classic, which is what's used in the tutorial, but I don't see why this would stop working.

Gazebo Fortress is totally different from Gazebo Classic, and so are also the plugins. Have you had a look into the documentation? It seems that you need other parameters, like the topic parameter.
Have a look at the code to get a list of all parameters.
Are there any error messages in the console output when you launch gazebo/spawn your model?
Furthermore, gz topics are not available in ROS automatically, and vice versa. See the docs.

Okay, thank you. I followed the tutorials and managed to get my robot moving. But is this Gazebo system compatible with Rviz? And with Nav2?

Gazebo Classic (gazebo_ros2_control) and Gazebo (ign_ros2_control/gz_ros2_control) are both "compatible". The communication therefore is limited only to a couple of topics.
